# Stopping a node by "Ctrl+C" doesn't update "rosnode list" command's result

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone. i am new to ros. i just started studying ros. i'm following tutorials for beginner now, and i found one thing that doesn't seem to be right. there's a tutorial titled "Understanding ROS Nodes" and it showed me the way to stop a node by pressing "CTRL+C" and to display currently running nodes on the screen by "rosnode list" command. here is the question. if I stop a node by pressing "CTRL+C",  shouldn't "rosnode list" command  "NOT" display the node I just stopped?  Apparently, it still displays the node although i stopped it. is this how it's supposed to be? or is this a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35303/stopping-a-node-by-%22ctrl+c%22-doesn%27t-update-%22rosnode-list%22-command%27s-result./) by [Seungeun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2501/seungeun-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the usual case this should not happen. If I am not mistaken, the node should unregister with the master when the last NodeHandle goes out of scope, and ros::shutdown() gets called. There might be a problem with the way your code is written which prevents this from happening. On the flip side, for *most* applications, a node that does not unregister should not constitute a problem.

To ensure that this is not a problem specific to the node you have written, try out some of the nodes already available in roscpp_tutorials. Try the following commands in order:

1. Start roscore
2. rosnode list
3. rosrun roscpp_tutorials talker
4. rosnode list
5. Ctrl+C the talker node
6. rosnode list

The rosnode list output for me looks something like this:

```
piyushk@piyushk-laptop:~$ rosnode list
/rosout
piyushk@piyushk-laptop:~$ rosnode list
/rosout
/talker
piyushk@piyushk-laptop:~$ rosnode list
/rosout
```

If your output looks similar to that above, it may be a problem in the code you've written. If not, we can try and debug the problem.

Piyush

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Seungeun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2501/seungeun-lee/) on 2012-05-31**:
Thanks for the answer~Piyush. I tried your suggestion and it worked fine as expected. The problem I mentioned earlier though happened when running "turtlesim_node"(of turtlesim package. a part of ros installation). so i guess it's a problem of something else. and i found out that the problem doesn't

**Comment by [Seungeun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2501/seungeun-lee/) on 2012-05-31**:
happen with ROS electric. I didn't try out every version of ros but the problem that didn't happen with "electric" happens with "fuerte" version seems that it's the problem of "fuerte" version of ros. is there a place within the wiki I can report this bug(I think)? and thank you again Piyush:)

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-06-01**:
You should post this bug on trac: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/